# "ctrls is not defined" error not sure where to define it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a CTRLS is not defined error and I know not where to define ctrls. I am a complete noob to angularJS and I am trying to call the rotten tomatoes API for movie searching. Where would I define CTRLS and how would I write the code?

```
angular.module('demoApp',[])
  .constant('apiKey', 'removed for security' )
  .constant('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0')

document.getElementById('searchBox').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {

        // construct the uri with our apikey
        var searchText = this.value;
        console.log('Enter works');

        ctrls.controller('resultsCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.search = searchText;
            console.log('control function works');
            $http.jsonp('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json', {
                params: {
                    q: 'toy',
                    page_limit: 10,
                    page: 1,
                    apikey: apiKey,
                    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'                    
                }
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: `ctrls` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrls is undefined. So you need to define which module that refers to.

This should assist you: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Example copied here for reference:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
}]);

<div ng-controller="DoubleController">
  Two times <input ng-model="num"> equals {{ double(num) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using ctrls is as though you had initially stored an AngularJS module into a variable.

for instance:

```
var ctrls = angular.module('demoApp', []);

ctrls
  .constant('apiKey', 'removed for security' )
  .constant('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0')

ctrls.controller(function($scope, $http){
//Logic Here
});
```